# Google Sheets API Browser Quickstart Client ID and API key

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api, api-key, secret-key

I am trying to follow the [Browser Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) for the Google Sheets API. In "Step 1: Turn on the Google Sheets API", the tutorial has buttons which create a new project and create an API key, but I can't use these because I don't have permission to create new projects (however, I do have "owner" role for an existing GCP project). The tutorial provides no explanation of how to get a Client ID and API key without the use of the embedded buttons - how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a existing project. You can add the Sheet API to it and then retrieve the credentials from said project.

First enter [Console Cloud](https://console.cloud.google.com). 
In there select the project where you need to enable the API calls.

[image]

---

[image]

After you have selected your project you need to enable the API for this project, to do so go to the [API dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard?). In there click on `ENABLE APIS AND SERVICES`:

[image]

In there look for the `Google Sheets API` and on founding it click on `ENABLE`:

After enabing this API you will need to [generate the credentials](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) click on `Create credentials > OAuth client ID`. After that you just need to fill the information and add the corresponding scopes.

After you have added your credentials you can download the JSON for you to use it.

[image]

---

For the `API key` you can do the same process but instead of `OAuth Client ID` do `Create credentials > API key`:

[image: API Key creation]

After that you can see the `API Key` from the [same page](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials).

If you need more information on how to enable API's and other functionalities refer to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/getting-started).

Comment: Thanks for this. I have created Oauth 2.0 credentials, and this provides a "Client ID" and "client secret". I tried using the "client secret" as the API key in the [browser quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js#step_2_set_up_the_sample) (see line `var API_KEY = '<YOUR_API_KEY>';`), but if I then use the HTML example, a 404 with the message "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key." is returned, where do I get the API key from?

Comment: Edited to add the `API Key` creation. Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks, that worked - the authorise button now appears. However, I get a 404 when I click the button to authorise, but that might be a different problem.

Comment: Remember to share the sheet with your service account. But if you still have problems you should open a new question so you can be answered there and not here buried in comments.